# An electrostatic boundary value problem: A hollow metal sphere submerged in a dielectric liquid

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, boundary-conditions

I am trying to solve the following problem. The physical situation goes as the following

Initially, a neutral hollow metal sphere is slightly submerged in a dielectric liquid. After adding a charge $Q$ to the hollow sphere, it becomes half submerged in the liquid due to the force between the charge $Q$ and the charged induced in the dielectric liquid. (See the image attached.) I wish to determine the electric potential everywhere after the sphere becoming half submerged. My initial approach is to use the standard method to solve the Laplace equation in each region and match the coefficients by the boundary conditions. But I would like to know is there any means to determine the potential in each region without solving the Laplace equation? By the way, I am also wondering whether the charge $Q$ only distributed in the upper half sphere which is not submerged in the liquid. Thanks.

(The figure illustrates the initial situation where the hollow metal sphere is neutral and only slightly submerged in the liquid before we add a charge $Q$ to it.)
[image]